# Should I get other Aggregate value from application service or entity?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I have Inventory, Catalog, and Sales bounded contexts.

I have this invariant:

> When creating catalog, we cannot sell more than what we have in Inventory

```
class CatalogApplicationService {
    void createCatalog(ProductId productId, int numToSell) {
        ProductValue pv = productService.byId(productId)
        // Catalog constructor will validate numToSell againts pv.numAvailable
        Catalog c = new Catalog(pv, numToSell)
        catalogRepository.save(c)
    }
}

class Catalog {
    Catalog(ProductValue pv, int numberToSell) {
        if (pv.numAvailable < numberToSell) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        setSku(pv.sku);
        setAmount(numberToSell);
    }
}
```

or should I pass along the service into Catalog

```
class CatalogApplicationService {
    void createCatalog(ProductId productId, int numToSell) {
        Catalog c = new Catalog(productService, numToSell)
        catalogRepository.save(c)
    }
}

class Catalog {
    Catalog(ProductService productService, int numberToSell) {
        ProductValue pv = productService.byId(productId)
        if (pv.numAvailable < numberToSell) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        setSku(pv.sku);
        setAmount(numberToSell);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about passing the `pv` to the `Catalog` constructor instead of the `ProductService`?  `Catalog c = new Catalog(productService.byId(productId), numToSell);`

Comment: yup that's my first option,

Comment: Oh yes, but I meant putting validation inside Catalog constructor

Comment: By passing pv into entity's creator, I am worried that I am leaking logic to ApplicationService though

Comment: @Fajarmf Good concerns. I wouldn't consider retrieving product details as business logic though, but more as supporting workflow logic. If determining the filtering rules to gather the data was very complex then it could be different, but here it's just a question of passing a `PoductId`. However what concerns me the most is your usage of the word `Catalog` to describe what seems to be an `Order`. Also, since the `Catalog` AR relies on external data it can only protect the rule in an eventually consistent manner (inventory could change while createCatalog executes).

Comment: No, I actually mean catalog for display. It has number to sell, which the view may display it as "only x number remains." I understand that I can use eventual consistency when inventory decreased, I would use it's event to update catalog number to sell as well. Catalog bc may have an invariant to only sell 85% of inventory. It fits well for that case. But for catalog creation I wonder how eventual consistency can help here.

Comment: @Fajarmf Not sure that I get what you mean by "catalog for display". In the case of displays there is no invariant enforcement. Even for display, it feels weird to me that every product has a `Catalog` concept. They might have a `CatalogEntry`, but certainly not a `Catalog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not inject services inside your aggregates (`Catalog`) but pass the data to them, in order to keep them as clean as possible, without unnecessary dependencies.

Also, you should use the ubiquitous language (UL) throughout your code. For example, throwing a generic `IllegalArgumentException` doesn't seem to be from from your UL.

Comment: One of my concern with letting ApplicationService to gather the data, is that it feels like some kind of domain logic there, which we should put in the Entity right?

Comment: Yes, the domain logic should be in the entities.

Comment: But I also have reservation for passing DomainService to entity, and wonder if it's good idea to do so

Comment: Do you mean, that ApplicationService, gathering data from other service(s) is not a domain logic?

Comment: Yes, it's not domain logic.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's like application service is using "Repository" to get data / entity right?... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Verifying a business logic is generally done at the *Service* layer. Models should be kept as only containing data, rather than logic. So, your first solution is advised.

Comment: Actually, models that just contain data (anemic models) are an anti-pattern: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: yeah, I was hoping to avoid anemic domain model. But a bit concern if I need to pass DomainService when calling Entity's contstructor

Comment: @Héctor I agree, but if one's using ORMs, which they typically do, I think it yields cleaner code, don't you?

Comment: Well, you can create a layer between the ORM entities and your "application". IMHO, if you use ORM entities as your application entities, your program is being data-driven instead of domain-driven and, in my experience, it's harder to maintain.